# Identify Rank of date ranges from datetime column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, gaps-and-islands

I have members, the group in which they belong and datetimes in which they were active. I want to find out which of the members had gap of more than 3 months between dates and I need to rank them.

| header 1 | header 2 | Create Date | Rank |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 11111 | EAM | 2022-01-27 12:23:28.474000000 | 1 |
| 11111 | EAM | 2022-08-25 10:41:15.500000000 | 2 |
| 11111 | EAM | 2022-09-01 18:15:07.362000000 | 2 |
| 11111 | EAM | 2022-09-08 13:03:38.859000000 | 2 |
| 11111 | EAM | 2022-10-06 18:15:07.245000000 | 2 |
| 11111 | PEM | 2022-07-25 10:41:15.500000000 | 1 |
| 11111 | PEM | 2022-08-25 10:41:15.500000000 | 1 |
| 11111 | PEM | 2022-09-26 13:03:38.859000000 | 1 |

The desired result is above with the rank; the table contains the data without the `Rank` column.

Comment: We need to know what your data looks like before your expected results; without it we would have to *guess* what it looks like and that could be grossly wrong.

Comment: It looks exactly like the above minus the rank column

Comment: i think that is the data

Comment: Your statement *"I was unable to add the table here.*" implied to me that it was something more "different", @M.Moore .

Comment: Oh no, my apologies. I just wasn’t able to copy paste the table without the rank

Answer (score 0):

One method is to use `LAG` to get the prior date, compared the 2 dates return 1 if it's more than 3 months, and then `SUM` those values in a windowed aggregate:

```sql
WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT header1,
           header2,
           CreateDate,
           CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(MONTH,LAG(CreateDate) OVER (PARTITION BY header2 ORDER BY CreateDate),CreateDate) > 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Counter
    FROM (VALUES(11111,'EAM',CONVERT(datetime2(7),'2022-01-27 12:23:28.474000000')),
                (11111,'EAM',CONVERT(datetime2(7),'2022-08-25 10:41:15.500000000')),
                (11111,'EAM',CONVERT(datetime2(7),'2022-09-01 18:15:07.362000000')),
                (11111,'EAM',CONVERT(datetime2(7),'2022-09-08 13:03:38.859000000')),
                (11111,'EAM',CONVERT(datetime2(7),'2022-10-06 18:15:07.245000000')),
                (11111,'PEM',CONVERT(datetime2(7),'2022-07-25 10:41:15.500000000')),
                (11111,'PEM',CONVERT(datetime2(7),'2022-08-25 10:41:15.500000000')),
                (11111,'PEM',CONVERT(datetime2(7),'2022-09-26 13:03:38.859000000')))V(header1,header2,CreateDate))
SELECT header1,
       header2,
       CreateDate,
       SUM(Counter) OVER (PARTITION BY header2 ORDER BY CreateDate) + 1 AS Rank
FROM CTE;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select  header1 
       ,header2 
       ,Create_Date
       ,dense_rank() over(partition by header1, header2 order by flg) as Rank
from
(
select  *
       ,case when datediff(month, Create_Date, lead(Create_Date) over(partition by header1, header2 order by Create_Date)) >= 3 then 0 else 1 end as flg
from    t
) t
```

| header1 | header2 | Create_Date | Rank |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 11111 | EAM | 2022-01-27 12:23:28.000 | 1 |
| 11111 | EAM | 2022-08-25 10:41:15.000 | 2 |
| 11111 | EAM | 2022-09-01 18:15:07.000 | 2 |
| 11111 | EAM | 2022-09-08 13:03:38.000 | 2 |
| 11111 | EAM | 2022-10-06 18:15:07.000 | 2 |
| 11111 | PEM | 2022-07-25 10:41:15.000 | 1 |
| 11111 | PEM | 2022-08-25 10:41:15.000 | 1 |
| 11111 | PEM | 2022-09-26 13:03:38.000 | 1 |

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/nvE-cgbm)